# How to switch out more than one pair of letters at once in a string?

Tags: python, string, replace

I switched out one pair of letters with `maketrans`, but I don't know to what to do if I wanted to switch more letters at the same time.

For example change the "a" to a "z". I know I can use `.replace`, but I don't know if that does it for all of the "a" in the string.

```
string = "Hello Sam!"

print(string.translate(string.maketrans("S", "P")))
```

Comment: `maketrans()` accepts strings longer than a single character :-)

Comment: According to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) you can give maketrans longer strings as JonSG says. You could use `string.maketrans("Sa", "Pz")` which will translate S➔P and also a➔z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.maketrans()` supports parameters of longer than a single character.  They represent the one for one translation.

```py
string = "Hello Sam!"
from_characters = "Sl"
to_characters   = "P$"
translator = str.maketrans(from_characters, to_characters)
print(string.translate(translator ))
```

Gives you:

`He$$o Pam!`